# Do i need an odometry input for robot_localization with only IMU data?

Tags: ros2, imu, robot-localization, tf2

I am now working to receive data from an IMU and then publish the transformation for SLAM with Lidar, using the robot_localization package for filter, and i will fuse this IMU with encoder later. I got some problems with the output of robot_localization, here is my ekf config file:

```
### ekf config file ###
ekf_filter_node:
ros__parameters:

    frequency: 30.0


    two_d_mode: false

    publish_acceleration: true

    publish_tf: true

    map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
    odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
    base_link_frame: base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" ifunspecified
    world_frame: map           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified

    imu0: imu
    imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  true, true, true,
                  true, true, true]
    imu0_differential: false
    imu0_relative: true
    imu0_queue_size: 5
    imu0_pose_rejection_threshold: 0.8                 # Note the difference in parameter names
    imu0_twist_rejection_threshold: 0.8                #
    imu0_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold: 0.8  #
    imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true
```

And when i run this, i get some issues below:

1. My launch file:

> [ekf_node-1] [ERROR] [1695693070.065820351] [ekf_filter_node]: Could
> not obtain transform from odom->base_link [ekf_node-1] [ERROR]
> [1695693070.099110713] [ekf_filter_node]: Could not obtain transform
> from odom->base_link

2. ros2 run tf2_ros tf2_echo odom base_link:

> [INFO] [1695692977.660285542] [tf2_echo]: Waiting for transform odom ->  base_link: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
> [INFO] [1695692979.648819499] [tf2_echo]: Waiting for transform odom ->  base_link: Invalid frame ID "odom" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist

Here is my transformation tree:
[image]

And my rqt_graph:

[image]

Can you guys tell me what is the problem? I had changed the world_frame in my efk config to odom, it give me some result but there is no translation, just the angle.

I am new to ROS2 and know that i should develop a coordinate map -> odom -> base_link, but i wonder whether i should do the odom publisher with IMU data, because i think this would increase the drift of my robot.

Thank you!